# PHP has $_GET variable, what does HTML have?

Tags: php, javascript, html, get

I know if I have a php page, I can pass variables to the next page through the url with $_GET. Such as:

> http://www.w3schools.com/welcome.php?fname=Peter&age=37

yields:

```
$currentName = $_GET["fname"]
$currentAge = $_GET["age"]
```

**Is there an equally easy way to do this in pure HTML (or javascript)?**

Comment: HTML is not a programming language. It's sort of possible with Javascript.

Comment: How would you do it in javascript?

Comment: Don't waste your time.. just use PHP

Comment: Here is how you do it in Javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values

Comment: Why would you want to if you're already using PHP even though it's not possible with html?

Comment: @Pjack — Presumably, he isn't.

Comment: If the OP would like to create full ajax'd pages.

Comment: I'm not already using PHP. However, PHP was the only language I was familiar with that did what I wanted.

Comment: Derp. Sorry for the duplicate - I'm a complete Javascript n00b and didn't know enough about Javascript to realize that! Thanks everyone for the quick and helpful feedback. You are the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `jQuery` you can get url parameters with `window.location` but parsing with `regex`

```
$.urlParameter = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    return results[1] || 0;
}

$.urlParameter('Parameter  name');
```

OR with JS

```
function urlParameter(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    return results[1] || 0;
}

urlParameter('Parameter  name');
```

Comment: That works without jQuery if you do `$={}` first.

Comment: Thanks for it just in simple Javascript. This is what I needed.